# Tree data structure implementation

Tags: ballerina

This is an implementation of [tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(data_structure)) data structure using Ballerina's [table](https://ballerina.io/learn/by-example/table-syntax/) collection and [query expressions](https://ballerina.io/learn/by-example/query-expressions/). The implementation allows bi-directional [traversal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal).

The two free traversing functions `walk1()` and `walk2()` demonstrate the usage.

I'm especially looking a guidance how to make the implementation more generic. I see the only non-generic part here is the `TreeNode.value` field. But any other comments and implementation alternatives as long as they allow bi-directional traversal are welcome too.

This is Ballerina 2201.2.0 (Swan Lake Update 2).

```
import ballerina/io;

public type TreeNode record {|
    readonly int id;
    string value;
    int parentId;
    int[] childIds = [];
|};

type TreeTable table<TreeNode> key(id);

class Tree {
    private TreeTable tree = table [];
    // TODO: might run out of numbers -> run-time panic
    // but we're not allowing removal yet so will do for now
    private int currentId = 1;

    public function init(string rootNodeValue) {
        self.tree.add({
            id: self.currentId,
            value: rootNodeValue,
            parentId: 0
        });
        self.currentId += 1;
    }

    public function add1(int parentId, string nodeValue) returns int {
        return self.add2(parentId, nodeValue)[0];
    }

    public function add2(int parentId, string... nodeValues) returns int[] {
        TreeNode parent = (
            from TreeNode item in self.tree
            where item.id == parentId
            limit 1
            select item
        )[0]; // <- TODO: might panic run-time but will do for now
        int [] ids = [];
        foreach string nodeValue in nodeValues {
            ids.push(self.currentId);
            self.tree.add({
                id: self.currentId,
                value: nodeValue,
                parentId: parentId
            });
            self.currentId += 1;
        }
        parent.childIds.push(...ids);
        return ids;
    }

    public function getRoot() returns TreeNode {
        return <TreeNode>self.getNodeById(1);
    }

    public function getNodeById(int id) returns TreeNode? {
        if id < 1 {
            return ();
        }
        TreeNode[] nodes = 
            from TreeNode item in self.tree
            where item.id == id
            limit 1
            select item
        ;
        if nodes.length() > 0 {
            return nodes[0];
        } else {
            return ();
        }
    }

    public function getNodeByValue(string nodeValue) returns TreeNode? {
        TreeNode[] nodes = 
            from TreeNode item in self.tree
            where item.value == nodeValue
            limit 1
            select item
        ;
        if nodes.length() > 0 {
            return nodes[0];
        } else {
            return ();
        }
    }

    public function toString() returns string {
        return self.tree.toString();
    }
}

function walk1(Tree tree, TreeNode? startNode) {
    if startNode !is () {
        io:print(startNode.value); io:print(" ");
        foreach var childId in startNode.childIds {
            TreeNode child = <TreeNode>tree.getNodeById(childId);
            walk1(tree, startNode = child);
        }
    }
}

function walk2(Tree tree, TreeNode? startNode) {
    if startNode !is () {
        io:print(startNode.value); io:print(" ");
        TreeNode? parent = tree.getNodeById(startNode.parentId);
        if parent is TreeNode {
            walk2(tree, parent);
        }
    }
}

//       A
//  B    C     D
// E F  G H  I J K
public function main() {
    Tree tree = new("A");
    
    int[] bc = tree.add2(1, "B", "C");
    int d = tree.add1(1, "D");
 
    _ = tree.add2(bc[0], "E", "F");
    _ = tree.add2(bc[1], "G", "H");
    _ = tree.add2(d, "I", "J", "K");
 
    // io:println(tree);

    walk1(tree, startNode = tree.getRoot()); io:println();
    walk1(tree, startNode = tree.getNodeByValue("C")); io:println();

    walk2(tree, startNode = tree.getNodeByValue("J")); io:println();
}
```

When the program is executed it prints:

```
A B E F C G H D I J K 
C G H 
J D A
```

as expected.